# openshift mobile site version not working when redirected

Tags: mobile, openshift, redirect

I have a website (example-example.rhcloud.com) on openshift hosting and website domain (example.com) on another hosting. I have redirected website example.com to example-example.rhcloud.com.

If I access example-example.rhcloud.com from a mobile device it works fine and opens the mobile version of the site. However, when I access example.com from a mobile device it is redirected to example-example.rhcloud.com but opens the regular version of the site.

What could be the problem?

Here's the code from example.com page

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
  <title>Example</title>

 </head>
 <frameset cols="100%,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
  <frame name="SiteShowFrame" src="http://example-example.rhcloud.com/">
 </frameset>
 <noframes>
  <body>
   Your browser doesn\'t support frames
  </body>
 </noframes>
</html>
```

The redirected site is loaded inside a frame. Could this be the problem with the mobile devices?

Comment: What are you using to determine if your rhcloud.com site should display the mobile or desktop version?  It seems that information is being stripped out of the request with the redirect.

Comment: I'm just loading the site on a mobile device, ie iphone, samsung etc

Comment: Also when the site is redirected I cannot use it, ie when I open the menu the site crashes.

Comment: I know this is very old post but I got same issue. Did you solve it ?